# Error building Games using GoogleApiClient

Tags: java, android, google-api-client

Am trying to build a game using `Google Play`'s GoogleApiClient. When I open app, my app crash. In logcat I get this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(8615): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal  
developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.  
E/AndroidRuntime(8615): at      
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.b(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(8615): at 
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.g(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(8615): at
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.gU(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(8615): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal
developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.  
E/AndroidRuntime(8615): at   
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.b(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(8615): at   
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.g(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(8615): at 
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.gU(Unknown Source)
```

This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)  
    .addApi(Games.API)  
    .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)  
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)  
    .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();    
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();   
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: You have to set the APP_ID inside <application> tag of Android Manifest.xml and set APP_ID value inside values.xml!!!

I had this error too!